# Angular still trying to look for templates even though I've $templateCached them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template

I'm trying to merge `gulp`, `angular ngbp`, and `ionic`.  So far I've restructured the sample app code to the ngbp style and I've compiled the templates into a `js` file so that they could be loaded into the `$templateCache` and then my app `js` files could just fetch templates from the cache.

In my `index.html`

```
   <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/ionic/js/ionic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/ionic/js/ionic-angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/browse/browse.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/browse/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/playlist/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/playlist/playlist.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/playlist/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/playlists/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/playlists/playlists.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/playlists/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/search/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/app/search/search.js"></script>
    <script src="/templates-app.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
```

In my `templates-app.js`

```
(function(module) {
try { module = angular.module("templates-app"); }
catch(err) { module = angular.module("templates-app", []); }
module.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("browse/templates/browse.tpl.html",
    "<ion-view view-title=\"Browse\">\n" +
    "  <ion-content>\n" +
    "    <h1>Browse</h1>\n" +
    "  </ion-content>\n" +
    "</ion-view>\n" +
    "");
}]);
})();

(function(module) {
try { module = angular.module("templates-app"); }
catch(err) { module = angular.module("templates-app", []); }
module.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("login/templates/login.tpl.html",

//..........
```

Sample route (browse/routes.js), templates are in `src/app/browse/templates/` (templates not included in build, thus, requiring templates-app.js to cache templates)

```
function BrowseConfig($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.browse', {
      url: "/browse",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "browse/templates/browse.tpl.html"
        }
      }
    })
  ;
}

angular.module('browse.routes', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', BrowseConfig])
;
```

This normally works fine with the generic `ngbp` project, but for some reason, when I load up `localhost:8080` for my project, the `angular` app still tries to `GET` the template files (404).  Why is my app not using the cache?

Comment: I don't understand.. You are storing a template with `"browse/templates/browse.tpl.html"`, but retrieving it with `"templates/browse.tpl.html"`?

Comment: @NewDev my bad, but the same thing still occurs even after I changed it to `browse/templates/browse.tpl.html`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include "templates-app" as a dependency in your "browse.routes" module otherwise he won't know the templates exist